# USB Wireless Mouse not working on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: usb, mouse

Suddenly yesterday, my wireless mouse stopped working, I tried unplugging and re-plugging the USB and didn't help.

Also, I replaced the battery with a new one, and then I tried using it on another PC and it worked perfectly, which would prove that there's nothing wrong with the mouse itself, it's an issue with the system.

For some reason, there's something preventing my mouse from working, noting, my PC does recognize it when I check by Terminal.

When the PC starts up the mouse works for like 2 seconds and then it stops permanently.

I have checked, 'usb-autosuspend.conf' and it's blank.

Please advise, it would be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!
Did already try other way to have it work but this one works well with Ubuntu just tried it.

To reinstall your mouse using a custom driver, the first thing you need to do is tell Ubuntu where to find the PPA. To do this, you need to have administrator privileges at least temporarily, so each command will start with "sudo" to make you a superuser, and you need to enter your password to execute the command. If you were installing the OpenRazer driver for Razr gaming devices, for example, you'd type "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrazer/stable" without the quotes. This gives you administrator privileges, gives the command to add a repository, and then tells your computer to use the stable version of the driver from that source. Once you've added the PPA, type "sudo apt update" to find the new software and then "sudo apt install openrazer-meta" – again, always without the quotes – to install the driver. Once you're done, restart the computer. The details will vary, depending which driver you're installing, but the process is much the same. You should find the installation directions for your specific driver on the project's web page.

For more option check the link below!

https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-reinstall-usb-mouse-drivers-in-ubuntu-using-the-command-line